# How do you get the name of a new file created using FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I'm monitoring a folder using FileSystemWatcher. If I download a file into there, how do I get the name of that downloaded file? For example, if I downloaded a file named TextFile.txt, how would I have it return that as a string? I am assuming this will work for all four triggers (changed, created, deleted, renamed)? I have IncludeSubdirectories set to true, so it should be able to do that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On the `OnCreated` event, add this code:

```
private void watcher_OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name); // this is what you're looking for.
}
```

**[See FileInfo Class @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)**

Answer (score 3):

```
private void watcher_OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    String Filename = Path.GetFilename(e.FullPath);
}
```